# Two-factor authentication implementation in PHP with HOTP

Tags: php, session, authentication, two-factor-authentication

At the moment I'm using a two-factor authentication with a random 6 digit code as the second factor, being sent via text-message or email. 
I now want to harden this by using the HOTP standard. And found a [nice class](https://github.com/Jakobo/hotp-php) which looks pretty neat.

But I was thinking about the implementation and best practice where to store the second factor and the way to check it. 
This is my suggested flow:

- User enters first authentication: username + password
- on success a session-row is added to the `session`-table; along with an OTP generated with the above mentioned class. And gets emailed/texted to user.
- Page reload
- Session is available but still has the OTP in the row, so a form is displayed to enter the second factor.
- Second-factor is being validated (three attemps, after that the whole session gets revoked)
- On success, the OTP gets removed from session-row and the `otp_done`-field gets update to true.
- page reload
- Session is active, `otp_done`=true so display application.

**Considerations**:
If the session gets hijacked (although being random and unique), they gain complete access. Is it better to store the otp in the session and validated it on every page load. But somehow this sounds double. And it only adds 6 digits more randomness to the equation.

Is there a standardized way to implement these OTP's?
Is my implementation good or is there a security flaw in it?

What `key` should be used to generate the OTP? Does the HOTP standard return different otp's for the same key?

```
sessions-table
id (int) | sessionid (str) | user (int) | otp (int|null) | otp_done (bool) | otp_tries (int)
```

Session_id is a 32-bits string generated with `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32))`

Comment: anybody answered to your question 6 years back? what your findings?